# setting http_headers in app.yaml doesn't work

Tags: google-app-engine, http-headers

I am developing an application with appengine 1.7.0 (python) and I am trying to add custom headers to static directories, via app.yaml, in this way:

```
- url: /js
  static_dir: static/js
  http_headers:
    X-Test-Http-Headers: yo
```

The problem is that the http header is not being set, even after restarting the application.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
it does not work either in development nor in production environments

**EDIT 2:**
debugging with Charles, the returned headers are these:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
ETag: "f_-W8g"
Date: Fri, 17 Aug 2012 09:40:10 GMT
Expires: Fri, 17 Aug 2012 09:40:15 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=5
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 8876
```

**EDIT 3:**
I found the problem. I changed the version and therefore the online version was not the deployed one. Restoring the version number made the deployed version available online, and therefore the headers were added:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Test-Http-Headers: yo
ETag: "DdNIcQ"
Date: Fri, 17 Aug 2012 10:19:01 GMT
Expires: Fri, 17 Aug 2012 10:19:06 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=5
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 8876
```

Comment: It's not working in the development environment (app engine launcher); I am going to check if it works in the deployed environment.

Comment: it does not work either in development nor in production environments

Comment: Which tool are you using to check the headers? Can you add a dummy parameter on the Url like `?test=fooooo` and see what happens?

Comment: I am using Charles as debugging tool. Even with adding ?test=fooo I still have the same headers (as displayed in the post).

Comment: I found the problem. I changed the version and therefore the online version was not the deployed one. Restoring the version number made the deployed version available online, and therefore the headers were added.

Comment: glad you've solved, you should close this question as "too localized" or delete it.